# Gravity Forms HTML Block Bug

Tags: html, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

I recently discovered a bug with gravity forms and I was wondering if you guys could help me and the community.
So, the problem it's with HTML content. I attached the images here. Basically, everything works just fine, when starting a new form, the HTML content it's displayed accordingly.
https://ibb.co/DRJrCzw
 But when someone goes to the next page and then comes back to the first one, the content it's displayed like in the image nr.2.
 https://ibb.co/Qrz8Wbd

Comment: Your image links are broken

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me!

JacKrac (https://www.reddit.com/user/JacKrac/)
Assuming you are a paying customer, have you reached out to support?
With that said, I believe it is because you are using shortcodes in the text.
The second time you visit it, the form content is likely rendered a different way compared to when the page first loads, likely with an Ajax request and/or javascript the second time around and the shortcode is not being processed.
One thing to try would be to copy the generated HTML and paste that into the HTML block in gravity forms, removing all the shortcode.
So, basically:
Open a text editor and save the current content you have in Gravity Forms, so you have a backup of it.
Open a page to view the form and then use your browser's HTML inspector to copy the HTML
Paste the HTML into gravity forms
If that fixes it, I would still reach out to them and ask them about how shortcode is handled within the html block and also let them know you think you found an issue.